# What are the reasons you would choose one code over the other between the ones I provide? Any suggestions to improve either of them?

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

The programs below calculate the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20. Which one would you choose between the two and why? 
1st piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ulong unsigned long

int main(void)
{
const ulong val = 20;
ulong x;
ulong y;

for (x = val; ; x += val)
{
    for (y = val - 1; y; y--)
    {
        if (x % y != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (y == 0)
    {
        printf("Answer = %u \n", x);
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

2nd piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool isDivisable(int x);

int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    while (true)
    {
        a+=20;
        if (isDivisable(a))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", a);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool isDivisable(int x)
{
    for (int i = 11; i < 21; i++)
    {
        if (x%i != 0)return false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Also, what does this for loop stand for?: 
for (y = val - 1; y; y--)
It iterates until it reaches what exactly? Would the code (y = val - 1; ; y--)  produce the same result?

Comment: Choose for what exactly?

Comment: Time efficiency. Anything else you might come with. Mostly time-complexity related issues. The 2nd one seems to run faster than the 1st.

Comment: Why would you ask us to explain some code to you if you supposedly wrote said code?

Comment: @AntonH I wrote the 2nd piece of code. Not the 1st one. It occurred to me that their time-complexity is the same, but the results appeared faster in the 1st code's case. I want to know why that is, since I cannot spot a difference that would make a difference.

Comment: Well, the second example is obviously more time-efficient.

Comment: If you wrote the second, you should definitely be able to see why it's faster...

Comment: @George You are referring to the part where code iterates from 11 onward in the function's loop. Right? I just felt like the 1st piece of code took less time to execute. I am not familiar with my IDE as of yet, in order to be able to check exactly how much time some code takes to run (total beginner).

Comment: I came up with an even faster implementation of this (look at my answer).

Comment: @AppWriter yes, but your answer does not compile:)

Comment: If the code works, the right site would probably be codereview.

Comment: @EOF Yeah, sorry. Still learning the ropes. New here.

Answer (score 1):

The number you are trying to find is a **[least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)** (LCM) of all numbers from 1 to 20. The LCM in this case will be equal to the product of multiplying the highest power of each prime divisor among numbers' prime factorization.

So, the result will be equal to `2^4 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 = 232792560`

If you want to find LCM of all numbers from `1` to `N`, you can simply use **[sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)** to find all prime numbers from `1` to `N` or choose any more optimized algorithm. Example in C (first peace of code rewritten):

```
#define ulong unsigned long

int main(void)
{
    const ulong val = 20;
    int isNotPrime[val+1];
    memset(isNotPrime, 0, sizeof(isNotPrime));

    isNotPrime[0] = isNotPrime[1] = 1;

    ulong res = 1;
    for (ulong i = 2; i <= val; ++i) {
        if (!isNotPrime[i]) {
            res *= pow(i, (int) (log(val) / log(i)));
        }

        for (ulong j = i*i; j <= val; j += i) {
            isNotPrime[j] = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Answer = %lu \n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be something else to take into account:

```c
// The least common multiple of numbers from 1 to 20.
// 2^4 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 = 232792560
// See also https://oeis.org/A003418 for details.
int lcm1_20() {
    return 232792560
}
```

If you are only interested in the respective value (and you do not intend to change the parameter "20"), then using the pre-computed value, and an explanatory comment might be good enough.

---

Among the two codes you provided, I would choose the first one, mostly because of the following aspects which make the second version look not very professional:

- the 2nd code doesn't consistently use white-spaces, e.g. `a+=20`, vs `int a = 20;`; also `if (x%i != 0)return false;` -- I think a white-space before the return looks better;
- the method name, `isDivisable` contains a typo.

Comment: It's not too hard to figure out yourself for such a small number. Just take the highest potence of each prime: 16 * 9 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19

Comment: @maraca indeed (I edited my comment), but oeis.org is a good resource in general. It might actually be faster to compute the function for 4-5 small values, search those numbers on google, for the right sequence to pop up first.

Answer (score -1):

The loop 'for (y = val - 1; y; y--)' will loop as long at y is not 0.  Your other example will never exit.

I'd prefer the first algorithm you proposed, since it eliminates an unnecessary function call, and is easier to read and understand.

Comment: It is?  ...................  Anyway, the function call could be inlined anyway.  The second example is much more time-efficient since it's more split up, and so takes less time to debug.

Comment: I said "I'd prefer"......   It's not the most optimal solution though.  It is just easier to understand without having to figure out the math of "Why is he looping from 11 to 21?"

Comment: @ChrisRouffer He is looping from 11 to 20 because there is no need to check 2 to 10 because: a) any number divisible by 12 is also divisible by 2, 3, 4 and 6. b) any number divisible by 14 is also divisible by 2 and 7. c) any number divisible by 15 is also by 3 and 5 d) any number divisible by 16 is also by 2, 4 and 8. e) any number divisible by 18 is also by 2, 3, 6 and 9. f) and finally any number divisible by 20 is also divisible by 2, 4, 5 and 10.

Comment: @SiggiSv I think he was making the point that it's less obvious at first glance what the code is doing, and might be more of a pain to debug, not saying he doesn't understand the "math".